# arithmetic operations in sqflite update query

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am looking for performing arithmetic operations like add subtract in flutter using SQFLITE in a flutter.

````
Batch batch = db.batch();
batch.update('table', {'Column': 'Column+1'}); ```

The result is:
{...., Column: Column+1,....}
No arithmetic Operations are being caaried out.
````

Comment: Just Found the answer: batch.rawUpdate(
          'UPDATE Table SET Column = Column+1 WHERE argument = ? ',
          ['argument']);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.